# __doc__ in python and using help() on a class

Tags: python, pydoc

I recently went to an interview and did some little programming test where they had a simple two class script that would calculate the area, side length, etc.. Of a shape it looked something like this:

```
class Shape(object):

    def __init__(self, side1, side2, side3, side4):
        self.side1 = side1
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def calc_area(self):
        pass

class Triangle(Shape):

    def calc_area(self):
        ... etc..
```

One of the questions they asked me was, *if we ran `help(Shape(3, 5, 5, 6))` what would happen assuming all objects have been initialized?* my answer was, nothing because there's no `docstring` or `__doc__`. It appears that I was marked down on this answer and I can't seem to understand why? Was I incorrect in thinking that nothing would happen when running `help()`?

Comment: Why don't you try running it yourself and see?

Comment: @jwodder Because I don't have the full source code, that's just what I have from memory. I guess I could make a basic class and try it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source of `pydoc.Helper` class (especially its `help()` method), which is essentially what you get when you call `help()`, you'll see that it will still get the basic structure of your object using the `inspect` module and a couple of other tricks.

The goal being, of course, to provide at least object/function signature to other developers if the original code writers didn't bother with writing the docs. Personally, I don't see the reason of `help()` existing in the global namespace anyway, but I understand why they've placed it both from a historical and philosophical perspective.

That being said, whoever interviewed you was, IMO, a jerk - this doesn't really have to do much with programming but with nitpicking which is, may I say, quite un-Pythonic. That is, assuming that they weren't trying to get you on the `@abstractmethod` descriptor, of course, which might be a valid question.

Comment: Yes that was a typo, I fixed it. I'm gonna go ahead an reread that part of the docs.. Apparently I'm an idiot lol

Comment: @user7351912 - You're not an idiot, idiot is the person who concots questions such as these on interviews - instead of trying to measure who has the best grasp of programming concepts these questions just show who has more encyclopedic knowledge about something completely non-consequential. If I had learned anything in my time 'from the other side of the fence' is to never ask such stupid questions anyone who I happen to interview.

Comment: Thank you that makes me feel a little better actually. Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things in your description of the code that could be what they were expecting you to mention. It's not completely obvious to me which of these is an error of your memory of the code, and which is the real issue, but they are both things to think about:

1. The `Shape` class you show has an `@abstractmethod` in it. If it had a properly defined metaclass (something derived from `abc.ABCMeta`), you wouldn't be able to create any instances from it. Only concrete subclasses that override each of the abstract methods could be instantiated. So they may have expected you to say "you can't call `help()` on `Shape(...)` because the latter causes a `TypeError`.
2. Calling `help` on an instance will give you a description of each of the class's methods, even if it doesn't have a docstring. If a docstring exists, it will be displayed first, but the documentation for the methods (and descriptors, etc.) will always follow.

Comment: I don't recall seeing any `abc.ABCMeta`, I guess I was just all around wrong. Idk why but for some reason I thought `help()` would run kind of like a `doctest` and only work if there was either a `__doc__` or `docstring` present..